# BIOS boots into non-OS Bluescreen

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, hardware-failure

After I left my Win 10 PC in Standby-mode, I woke it up and there only was a black screen with a blinking, white cursor. I tried to restart it, it showed the same black screen without booting the BIOS.

I did a CMOS-reset and after that, I got into BIOS-screen and Windows told me, it had the problem "Inaccessible boot device". I went into Sys-repair.

Automatic repair didn't work, but safe boot did. After that, everything was normal, I restarted once without problems, but the second time, the screen went black again and now it didn't even have a cursor and the PC began restarting all the time.

I tried to plug the SSD into another PC, Windows worked without problems.

The interesting thing is, that the BIOS starts from time to time, but if it does, it doesn't react to the keyboard, though the lights on the keyboard are functional. It boots into a blue screen, which doesn't fill the whole screen and doesn't show any information and 5 secs later, it restarts again. The Bluescreen is not OS-related because there isn't any drive plugged in.

I've tried multiple CMOS-Resets, to which the MB reacts, but which doesn't fix anything, I used the Clear-Bios Jumper and changed the BIOS-Battery. Non of this fixed it. 
It never gives an audio-signal, except if I remove the RAM, but then it also doesn't boot anymore.

I use a Gigabyte GA-B75M-D3P (rev. 1.0) with DualBios.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Try (re)flashing the BIOS with the latest version, if that doesn't help it sounds to me like you have hardware failure (motherboard, video adapter, and/or RAM).

Comment: For flashing I would've to connect an USB/Floppy-drive and select it in the Boot-menu, wouldn't I? If Yes, I can't do it, because the MB doesn't react to the Keyboard, so I can't make changes to the Boot-menu.

Comment: If it has DualBIOS you should be able to switch between the two firmware loads.  Have you done that?